# Core Data Filter by Distance From Current User Location

Tags: database, core-data, realm, nsfetchedresultscontroller, yapdatabase

I have an NSManagedObject class that's persisted in a SQLite database in Core Data. This object has persistent Latitude and Longitude properties. I'm trying to create an NSFetchedRequestController that fetches all of the instances of that class that are within a certain distance from the user. Having done some research, it seems impossible to do this with Core Data, because Core Data only supports bounding-box style queries, not predicates with blocks.

For example, I have a class of Groups with latitude and longitude properties. Given the latitude and longitude (of, say, a user), fetch all groups that are within a 6 mile radius of the given latitude and longitude.

```
class Group{
     var latitude: Float
     var longitude: Float
}
```

I'd like to take advantage of Core Data's R-Tree Indexing to do a fast bounding-box query on the latitudes and longitudes of instances of my class near my user. Then I'd like to filter the results with a more precise predicate, using my own block of code to see which of the instances are within my users current location. Here's the "Bounding box" query.

```
let request: NSFetchRequest<Group> = Group.fetchRequest()
let (topLeft,bottomRight) = boundingBox(center: center, radius: searchRadius)
let maxLat = topLeft.latitude
let minLon = topLeft.longitude
let minLat = bottomRight.latitude
let maxLon = bottomRight.longitude
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "(%f < longitude AND longitude < %f) AND (%f < latitude AND latitude < %f)", minLon, maxLon, minLat, maxLat)
request.predicate = predicate
```

The problem is that I'd like a fetch that looked like this:

```
let location: CLLocation = /* Initialize a CLLocation */

let predicate = NSPredicate { (obj, _) -> Bool in
     let object = obj as! Group
     let objLocation = CLLocation(latitude: Double(object.latitude), longitude: Double(object.longitude))
     return location.distance(from: objLocation) < 9656 //6 miles in meters
}
```

NSFetched results controller doesn't allow predicate with block. There's a significant difference between these two fetches. The first gets all groups in a Bounding Box, (the minLat, minLon, maxLat, and maxLat), the latter gets all groups in a Circle of a given radius.

I want to then use an NSFetchedRequestController to display the results in a table, and take advantage of the nice auto-update features. But of course, Core Data only supports bounding-box style queries, not the two-step filter method I need. Is there a proper solution?

I'm open to using other databases, if Core Data simply won't work with this type of use. I took a look at YapDatabase, and it seems more flexible, and includes R-Tree indexing, but I'm concerned that it's not well supported. Realm doesn't support R-Tree Indexing.

Comment: The question is a bit unclear - are you stating you want to find other users within a certain distance of the given user via the radius? If so what does that have to do specifically with Core Data (an object graph)? R-Tree's have a minimum bounding 'box' so can you clarify what the issue is? Do you have some example code that you're having difficulty with? Perhaps if you can include that in the question it will add clarity.

Comment: @Jay I assume there are many open questions. To quote only two: 1.) There is a R-Tree fetchIndex option available with Core Data (and when switched on actually all SQLite R*Tree tables will be generated) but it is unclear how a NSPredicate must look like in order to take advantage of this feature 2.) If such a NSPredicate could be found he would like to make it _more precise_ with own functions that filter the results from the fetch, and the function should be implemented as a "block" (or closure in Swift).

Comment: @mark61 Core Data offers an R-Tree option by setting the FetchIndex element type with [NSFetchIndexElementType.rTree](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsfetchindexelementtype/rtree) which is an enum. Probably reading through the [NSManagedObjectModel](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsmanagedobjectmodel) documentation will add a bit more clarity so I included the link. There really isn't a 'switching on' - if that property is set, that fetch request will be r-tree and can be used with an NSPredicate; `fetchRequest.predicate = predicate`.

Comment: @Jay Selecting _NSFetchIndexElementType.rTree_ is what i mean with _switiching on_. Sorry if it was ambiguous.  Do you have an example of a predicate format string that uses the SQLite rTree index table with Core Data?

Comment: We don't know what the models look like or what we are predicate-ing on so there's really not enough information in the question to know what to propose. It could be super complex depending on that structure. It's also not clear what the OP is after - how to do the initial query, how to filter the results or how to use the controller to display the results so it could be a VERY long answer.

Comment: @Jay Updated with additional details. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @mark61 Updated

Comment: Just FYI: you mention using FRC because of the "nice auto-update features" - just checking what updates you are monitoring: new/amended/deleted objects will update fine, but the FRC will not auto-update to reflect changes resulting from the user's location changing.

Comment: Hello @izaguirrejoe  any chance you found a solution to this problem?

Comment: Hey @elight, I ended up going in a totally different direction, building out my own backend using Ruby on Rails and letting the PostGIS database take care of the distance queries for me. Not for the faint of heart.